# Why can't a subroutine with assumed-shape argument have an internal function?

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I have a subroutine with an assumed-shape array that also contains an internal function:

```
subroutine test(x)
   real x(:)
contains
   function a()
   end
end
```

When I try to compile it with f2py (`f2py -c test.f90 -m test`), the following error gets printed:

```
gfortran:f77: /tmp/tmphb_l9bkr/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/test-f2pywrappers.f
/tmp/tmphb_l9bkr/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/test-f2pywrappers.f:11:10:

           function a() ! in :test:test.f90:test
          1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
/tmp/tmphb_l9bkr/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/test-f2pywrappers.f:13:13:

           end function a
             1
Error: Expecting END SUBROUTINE statement at (1)
```

However, if I remove either the internal function `a()`, or give an explicit shape to the array (e.g. `real x(5)`), it compiles fine. What's wrong with my code as given above?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. What happens when you use `end function`? It used to be required. You should report your compiler version and try the latest one.

Comment: The above code snippet and errors reported are not consistent. Can you please post the actual code you are using when the above errors are generated. I also note the characters f77 suggesting this is being treated as Fortran 77 in which contained functions did not exist, and that would explain the above errors assuming the code you are actually using is not far different from the one you posted. I don't know f2py, but it may be this is stuck 3 decades ago and assumes Fortran 77,

Comment: @IanBush Actually, the code appears to be consistent with the error message. That is because the code goes through the f2py pre-processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation appears to be quite peculiar. To be more certain what, motivated by the `end function a` error message, happens I added the full end statements

```
subroutine test(x)
   real x
contains
   function a()
   end function a
end subroutine test
```

as you can see in the error message, the gfortran error does not come from your original source code, but frome a different source code in the `/tmp/` directory. If you open it it looks like this:

```
C     -*- fortran -*-
C     This file is autogenerated with f2py (version:2)
C     It contains Fortran 77 wrappers to fortran functions.

      subroutine f2pywraptest (x, f2py_x_d0)
      integer f2py_x_d0
      real x(f2py_x_d0)
      interface
      subroutine test(x) 
          real, dimension(:) :: x
          function a() ! in :nestedf:nestedf.f90:test
          end function a
      end subroutine test
      end interface
      call test(x)
      end
```

It is a wrapper intended to call your subroutine. The reason for that is to make it easier for Python to call your code without requiring Python to understand the assumed shape argument. However, f2py does not correctly understand the internal function when creating the interface.

Unfortunately, you have to choose. Either you can have the assumed shape argument or you can have an internal function. But f2py does not understand both. Or you would have to somehow intercept the f2py temporary file and fix it before proceeding further but I do not know how that could be done.

I would not get too much distracted with the *Fortran 77* mentioned in the wrapper source. They probably mean that the wrapper itself can be called without an explicit interface and that the source file is fixed-form. But it clearly contains Fortran 90 features.